# my code is not running: to print random numbers between 1 to 1000 every second

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script>
 function generateTerms()
 {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = generateTerms;
 }
 setInterval(generateTerms,1000); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my code is not running...not generating numbers

Comment: you `return` *before* `document.getElementById()` so it never executes.  `generateTerms` is a function object, its probably no what you want to write as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `return` before the setting `innerHTML`. `return` stops the further execution of the function. You need to assign it to a random value.

**Note:** If you want to get the value returned by a function in other function then you should use `()` to call the function.(Here it won't work)

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script>
 function generateTerms()
 {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = random;
 }
 setInterval(generateTerms,1000); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nivi Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with answer.

Answer (score 1):

`return` leaves the scope of the function and returns a value. The code below it won't be executed. Plus, `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = generateTerms;` is a non sense, there is no variable named `generateTerms`

Change your function to this :

```
function generateTerms()
{
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNumber;
}
```

```js
function generateTerms()
{
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNumber;
}
setInterval(generateTerms,1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
```